# Plugin para wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Estoy tratando de hacer un plugin para wordpress en el cual le muestre al cliente el estado de cuenta de sus clientes.
Lo que hago es simple, una consulta a una base de datos en la cual hay una lista de clientes y el estado de los mismo, si estan activos o no.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Clienre
* Plugin URI: http://cliente.com.ar/
* Description: Sistema de usuarios para cliente.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: cliente
* Author URI: http://cliente.com.ar/
* Text Domain: cliente
* License: GLP2
* @package cliente
*/

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$udate = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
$rw = $udate->fetch();
echo $rw['code'];
?>
```

Todo funciona bien, pero el problema es que los datos se ven en la pagina del cliente y no en el escritorio. Quiero hacer algo asi como WooCommerce, pero mas simple, mucho mas simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar la información en forma de widget en el escritorio, tal y como indica [la documentación](https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API).

Por ejemplo:

```
function cliente_add_dashboard_widgets() {

    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
                 'cliente_dashboard_widget',         // Widget slug.
                 'Estado de la Cuenta',              // Titulo.
                 'cliente_dashboard_widget_function' // Función que muestra el contenido.
        );  
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'cliente_add_dashboard_widgets' );

/**
 * Esta es la función que muestra los datos.
 */
function cliente_dashboard_widget_function() {

    try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $udate = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
    $rw = $udate->fetch();
    echo "Aquí puedes escribir más cosas si quieres: ".$rw['code'];

}
```

Comment: Gracias @a-cedano, ahora voy a leer más la documentación que dejaste. Me sirvio mucho.